# Can't upgrade to package version listed on Launchpad

Tags: apt, ppa, launchpad, 20.10

I'm running Groovy, and trying to upgrade **figma-linux** to the latest version which was [listed in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Echrdevs/+archive/ubuntu/figma/+packages) around half an hour ago.

I've currently got version `0.6.3-1` installed. I've run `apt update`, and `apt` isn't giving me the option to upgrade to the new version `0.6.4`.

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy figma-linux 
figma-linux:
  Installed: 0.6.3-1ubuntu0
  Candidate: 0.6.3-1ubuntu0
  Version table:
 *** 0.6.3-1ubuntu0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chrdevs/figma/ubuntu groovy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

How do I upgrade this package to `0.6.4`?

Comment: The latest build released for *groovy* in that PPA was built on 2020-09-07.  The later version are for *hirsute* and not *groovy*.   https://launchpad.net/%7Echrdevs/+archive/ubuntu/figma/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest build released for *groovy* in that PPA was built on 2020-09-07.  The later version is for *hirsute* and not *groovy*.

https://launchpad.net/%7Echrdevs/+archive/ubuntu/figma/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=groovy

The build of 0.6.4 is

```
figma-linux - 0.6.4-1ubuntu0    (changes file)  48 minutes ago  Published   Hirsute     Graphics    All builds were built successfully.
figma-linux - 0.6.3-1ubuntu0    (changes file)  2020-09-07  Published   Xenial  Graphics    All builds were built successfully.
figma-linux - 0.6.3-1ubuntu0    (changes file)  2020-09-07  Published   Bionic  Graphics    All builds were built successfully.
figma-linux - 0.6.3-1ubuntu0    (changes file)  2020-09-07  Published   Focal   Graphics    All builds were built successfully.
figma-linux - 0.6.3-1ubuntu0    (changes file)  2020-09-07  Published   Groovy  Graphics
```

Note the "**Hirsute**"